# How to get the first key and value pair from a hash table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to get the first key and value key from a hash table in ruby. I don't know the key values of the hash because it is passed to the method. I cant find anywhere online how to find the first key/value as a separate hash table. 
I think `hash[0]` will just try to find an element with a name 0 it just returns `nil` when I run the code.

I know I can find the key name and the value and then create a new hash from them but i wonder if there is an easier way to do this so I get a hash right away.

here is my code:

```
def rps_game_winner(game)

rock_in_hash = game.invert['R']
paper_in_hash = game.invert['P']
scissors_in_hash = game.invert['S']

if(rock_in_hash)
      if(paper_in_hash)
        return paper_in_hash;
      elsif(scissors_in_hash)
        return rock_in_hash
      end
    elsif(paper_in_hash)
      if(rock_in_hash)
        return paper_in_hash
      elsif(scissors_in_hash)
        return scissors_in_hash
      end
    end
        key = game.keys[-1]
        value = game.values[-1]
            winner = {key => value}
    return winner 
    end

game_one = { "Bob" => 'P', "Jim" => 'P' }

puts rps_game_winner(game_one)
```

This gets me the correct result the problem is I don't understand why it's -1 instead of zero...
And i was hoping there was a better way to get the first key/value pair of a hash table instead of creating new hash table with the key and value you retrieved from the previous table.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can just do

```
key, value = hash.first
```

or if you prefer:

```
key = hash.keys[0]
value = hash.values[0]
```

Then maybe:

```
new_hash = {key => value}
```

Comment: your first example trows Line 24:in `rps_game_winner': undefined method `first' for {"Jim"=>"P", "Bob"=>"P"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
 from t.rb:31. But what really blew my mind is that when i tried the second method (which I was trying to avoid because i thought there was an easier way) i get the second entry Bob P and whats even stranger when i call it with keys[-1] values[-1] i get the first entry JimP I completly dont understand whats going on. Do you have any ideas. Im using codepad to interpret my script.

Comment: I think you're using 1.8, hashes were different then.

Comment: I just tested this in IRB, and it seems the first method (hash.first) is far better. It doesn't have to construct the array of all keys/values, as it grabs the first one directly. The second method will create arrays holding all keys/values in memory, and then it can grab the first elements from those arrays. If your hash is large, this will take much longer.

Comment: How would you return the first ten values of your hash?

Comment: @AlfonsoVergara check my answer below :)

Answer (score 50):

There is a **shorter answer** that does not require you to use extra variables:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 , "c" => 300, "d" => 400, "e" => 500}
Hash[*h.first] #=> {"a" => 100}
```

Or if you want to **retrieve a key/value at a any single position**

```
Hash[*h.to_a.at(1)] #=> {"b" => 200}
```

Or **retrieve a key/values from a range of positions**:

```
 Hash[h.to_a[1,3]] #=> {"b"=>200, "c"=>300, "d"=>400}
```

Comment: Thank you for this much more concise answer! The idea of storing the key and value to variables just for this purpose definitely isn't ideal.

This should be the top answer!

Comment: What is the meaning of the *?

Comment: it's the ruby splat operator. More info here: http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/

Comment: @metakungfu, I think the second and third method is not memory efficient as it has to convert the whole hash to an array. A little better solution would be to use h.keys because then it will only create a single array instead of an array containing both keys and values.

Comment: @KashifUmairLiaqat - memory efficiency is relative. If you are working with large hash or memory constrained environment, you should manually pick your keys & values. At the end, it's always a tradeoff between readability & performance.

Comment: When it comes to the enterprise applications, every small byte that you can save counts. When you can avoid creating two arrays and get the result by only creating one array then why use additional memory even if it's very small hash?

Answer (score 6):

```
[hash.first].to_h
```

Another way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
my_hash = { "a" => "first", "b" => "second" }

{ my_hash.keys.first => my_hash.values.first }
```

This works too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).